# Getting Null value in token

Tags: java, paypal, token, checkout

I am try to integrate a paypal express checkout in my java application.When I try to access the token,it returns `null`.Here is my code

```
SetExpressCheckoutResponseType set=s.setExpressCheck();
 if(set!=null)
 System.out.println(set.getToken());
```

it prints `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhm that is a little bit too less information.
What is `s`. What librarby|framework do you use?
Did you read [express-checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/overview-ec/)?
I'm guessing that you use the Paypal Api.

Comment: i put different value for order total and item amount.now i correct it.now it's return the token as i am expected.